# Analysing data from non-equivalent groups in a quasi-experimental design

Tags: statistical-significance, experiment-design

I am doing a research on two groups, one experimental and one control, which are not randomly selected. In fact the two groups are *intact groups*. The purpose is to find the effect of the number of languages that the learners know on their academic achievement. The selected design is [Pretest Posttest Nonequivalent Group](http://www.socialresearchmethods.net/kb/quasnegd.php).

Which statistical method should I use to analyze the data?

Comment: Can you say more about what you mean when you say the groups are not randomly selected? Also, what do you mean by "_intact groups_?"

Comment: by intact groups, I mean 'the naturally assembled groups', 'intact classes' and when I say the groups are not randomly selected I mean 'I can not use the process of random selection due to the nature of my study so my samples are not random samples.'

Answer (score 2):

It sounds like you want some form of regression, depending on how your dependent variable (academic achievement) is measured.  If it's something like grade point average, then linear regression is a good start.

Then the question is how to measure "languages known". Clearly, it's a count variable (that is, it has to be a non-negative integer; in this case, a positive integer) but (depending on where you are doing this) you may have a huge preponderance of 1's.

You will also want to include covariates that relate to achievement.  You *might* want to do some sort of matching, possibly propensity scores.

Comment: what about the other methods such as ANOVA, t-test or even the Mann-Whitney U test? I have two variables, one independent (the number of the languages the students know) and one dependent variable. I have two groups as I said before. the observations are independent. But I'm not sure about whether the variables are interval or nominal. How to find? thank you

Comment: ANOVA is regression (they are mathematically equivalent). 

If you only have two variables, then you can do a t-test. I suggest, though, that you try to get more variables, especially for a non-equivalent design, in order to control for things known to be linked to achievement.

Comment: I, myself, think that t-test is appropriate although I've read the studies that have two two variables and two groups but they use ANOVA and I don't know how. one point that makes it difficult for me to choose t-test is that it is a kind of parametric tests and one assumption for parametric tests is the issue of random selection which my study lacks. am I correct? thanks

Comment: A t-test is just an ANOVA with only 2 groups. ANOVA is also parametric. The assumption of random selection isn't related to parametric vs. non-parametric; it's related to how generalizable the results are. You need more variables to try to control for the non-random selection.

Comment: even if I try to control the confounding variable such as age, sex, educational level, etc., i should be worry about the non-random selection problem?

Comment: Yes. Because you don't know what you haven't controlled for. People who know more languages are going to be different from those who know fewer in all sorts of ways; many of them related to educational achievement. That doesn't mean you can't do the study, but you have to be very careful not to attribute causality.